# How can I deploy a website on Heroku with parcel?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern, parcel, parceljs

I want to deploy website on Heroku which created using MERN. I created it with parcel. When I deploy on Heroku, It shows following error and I can't deploy it on heroku.
How can I fix this issue?
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVWen.png)

**Package.json**

```html
{
  "name": "TestProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel public/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dropzone": "^5.9.2",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi racketman, you need to provide more information in order someone to help you, what you have provided is not enough to understand the problem

Comment: Hi Diego. Thank you for replying. What kind of details are you expecting?

Comment: When you post a question, you want people to help you, in order to make that happen, try to give all the information people should need, like, package.json, file's structure, code, explain thing by thing the process you did to get where you've gotten and explain what you want to happen with your code/project whatever, what you expect to get, so, i encourage you to make another post, but this time like a real one, wish you the best !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "parcel: Permission denied" on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826703/how-to-fix-parcel-permission-denied-on-heroku)

Comment: @ceejayoz no it's not

Answer (score 0):

Heroku would look for a build command for production in there.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build",
    "install": "npm install",
    "start": "....",
  },
```