# How to fix "parcel: Permission denied" on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mern, heroku-cli, parcel, parceljs

I want to deploy my application on Heroku but it shows "parcel: Permission denied" error on Heroku cli. My project consist with two project.

1. Backend - Node, expressjs
2. Frontend - React

Project was connected with [concurrently npm packege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRd0O.jpg)

This is main package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "mainPro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd backend && node server.js",
    "server": "cd backend && nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd frontend && npm run start",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4",
    "npm": "6.14.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

This is fronend package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "FrontendFolder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel public/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@iconscout/react-unicons": "^1.1.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dropzone": "^5.9.2",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2"
  }
}
```

This is backend package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.0",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

[Heroku CLI logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRd0O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add `build` in front-side;

```
"build": "parcel build public/index.html",
"heroku-postbuild": "parcel build public/index.html"
```

Comment: Should I remove "start": "parcel public/index.html"?

Comment: Still same issue